# Can't add foreign key to an existing table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to add foreign key to an existing table `questions` which has 1000 above questions of different categories in it. But when I am trying to add foreign key mysql throws error as below.

`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`question_bank`.`#sql-af8_1d0`, CONSTRAINT`cat_id`FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES`db_category`(`cat_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

category table `db_category` structure.
[image]

questions table `db_questions` structure.
[image]

Comment: You have orphan records, meaning not all categories are listed in the category table. fix it and try again. Hint: SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)

Comment: @Pred Thanks for your reply. I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before adding a foreign key you should ensure it fits with the actual data.
The error is simple, you have some rows on `questions` table with wrongs value on `cat_id`

Just delete that rows, or create new categories. You can check the problematic rows with:

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE cat_id NOT IN (SELECT cat_id from category)
```

Comment: Thank you again. I deleted all problematic rows and created foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You cant add a `foreign key` to that table because you must check first if the `primary key` table has a `record exists` value same with `foreign key` table.
according to `primary column` value  and `foreign key` column value.

Comment: Primary key table value first before foreign key table value.